# Test class for a JsonParser in Apex

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

I'm a newbee with Apex and tryingto test one of my Apex class but just got a coverage of 25%.

I don t even think it is really testing my class , because just some variable declaration and some if statement turns on blue after the test. maybe somebody here can give me some directive for this.

So, I have let say a JsonParser class, that take a Http response as parameter and it is suppose to find to particular values in order to construct one object named crane.

So a crane has as fields:

My object here is a crane and has as fields:

```
public class JsonToCranesParser {



public static List<Crane__c> JsonToCranes(HTTPResponse res) {
    
    // create Parser
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

    // Define lists for my crane fields

    List<String> Ids = new List<String>();
    List<String> CraneType= new List<String>();
    List<String> CraneCategory = new List<String>();
    List<String> CraneControls= new List<String>();
    List<String> LoadCapacityType_0= new List<String>();
    List<String> TrackWidthCraneType_0= new List<String>();
    List<String> EngineControl_0= new List<String>();
    List<String> SellerCompany= new List<String>();
    List<Double> DemontageNummer= new List<Double>();
    List<Double> UsablePendulumStrutRadius= new List<Double>();
    List<Double> UsableSolidStrutRadius= new List<Double>();
    List<Double> LoadCapacityWeight_0= new List<Double>();
    List<Double> TrackWidthCrane_0= new List<Double>();    
    
    List<String> strList= new List<String>{'craneType','craneCategory','craneControls','loadCapacityType_0','trackWidthCraneType_0','engineControl_0','sellerCompany'};
    List<String> DblList= new List<String>{'dismantlingnumber','usablePendulumStrutRadius','usableSolidStrutRadius','loadCapacityWeight_0','trackWidthCrane_0'};
    String tmp;
    String tmp2;
    
    
    
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'id')) {
            while (parser.getText() != 'stringValue'){
                parser.nextToken();
            }

            parser.nextToken();
            Ids.add(parser.getText());
        }
        
        

        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (strList.contains(parser.getText()))) {
            
            tmp= parser.getText();
            while (parser.getText() != 'value'){
                parser.nextToken();
            } 

            parser.nextToken();
            parser.nextToken();
            parser.nextToken();
             

            switch on tmp {
                
                when 'craneType' {
                    CraneType.add(parser.getText());
                }   

                when 'craneCategory' {
                    CraneCategory.add(parser.getText());
                }

                when 'craneControls' {
                    CraneControls.add(parser.getText());
                }

                when 'loadCapacityType_0' {
                    LoadCapacityType_0.add(parser.getText());
                }

                when 'trackWidthCraneType_0' {
                    TrackWidthCraneType_0.add(parser.getText());
                }

                when 'engineControl_0' {
                    EngineControl_0.add(parser.getText());
                }
                
                when 'sellerCompany' {
                    SellerCompany.add(parser.getText());
                }    
            }   
         }
        
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (dblList.contains(parser.getText()))) {
            tmp2= parser.getText();
            
            while (parser.getText() != 'value'){
                parser.nextToken();
            }

            parser.nextToken();
            parser.nextToken();
            parser.nextToken();

            switch on tmp2 {
                when 'dismantlingnumber' {  
                    DemontageNummer.add(parser.getDoubleValue()); 
                }   
                
                when 'usablePendulumStrutRadius' {  
                    UsablePendulumStrutRadius.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                }
                
                when 'usableSolidStrutRadius' { 
                    UsableSolidStrutRadius.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                }
                
                when 'loadCapacityWeight_0' {
                    LoadCapacityWeight_0.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                }
    
                when 'trackWidthCrane_0' {
                    TrackWidthCrane_0.add(parser.getDoubleValue());
                }  
            } 
         } 
    }

List<Crane__c> myCranes = new List<Crane__c>();        


// we create a crane list with the data we get from the firestore database

for(Integer i = 0; i < Ids.size(); i++){
    Crane__c myCurrentCrane = new Crane__c();
    myCurrentCrane.firestore_id__c = Ids[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Crane_Category__c = CraneCategory[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Crane_Type__c = CraneType[i];
    myCurrentCrane.CraneControls__c =CraneControls[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Engine_Control__c = EngineControl_0[i];
    myCurrentCrane.LoadCapacityType__c = LoadCapacityType_0[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Track_Width_Crane_Type__c = TrackWidthCraneType_0[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Seller_Company__c = SellerCompany[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Demontage_Number__c = DemontageNummer[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Load_Capacity_Weight__c = LoadCapacityWeight_0[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Track_Width_Crane__c = TrackWidthCrane_0[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Usable_Pendulum_Radius__c = UsablePendulumStrutRadius[i];
    myCurrentCrane.Usable_Solid_Radius__c = UsableSolidStrutRadius[i];
    myCranes.add(myCurrentCrane);
}


System.debug('Ids: ' + Ids);
System.debug('CraneType: ' + CraneType);
System.debug('CraneCategory: ' + CraneCategory); 
System.debug('CraneControls: ' + CraneControls); 
System.debug('LoadCapacityType_0: ' + LoadCapacityType_0);
System.debug('TrackWidthCraneType_0: ' + TrackWidthCraneType_0); 
System.debug('EngineControl_0: ' + EngineControl_0); 
System.debug('SellerCompany: ' + SellerCompany); 
    
System.debug('DemontageNummer: ' + DemontageNummer); 
System.debug('UsablePendulumStrutRadius: ' + UsablePendulumStrutRadius); 
System.debug('UsableSolidStrutRadius: ' + UsableSolidStrutRadius); 
System.debug('LoadCapacityWeight_0: ' + LoadCapacityWeight_0); 
System.debug('TrackWidthCrane_0: ' + TrackWidthCrane_0); 



    List<Crane__c> SalesForceCranes = new List<Crane__c>();
     
    SalesForceCranes= [SELECT Id, firestore_id__c FROM Crane__c];
    
          
 // As we want to upsert cranes, we have to get their Saleforce Id if they already exist in Salesforce   
    for(Crane__c var1 : myCranes){
         for(Crane__c var2 : SalesForceCranes){
             
             if (var1.firestore_id__c == var2.firestore_id__c) {
                 var1.Id=var2.Id;
        
                 }            
      }
                
    }
    
    upsert myCranes;   
    return myCranes;
   
}
```

}

and in my test class, I create test data as an Http Response, and the point is that normally after running my class method, I want to compare if the return values are the expected one like this

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
```

public class JsonToCranesParserTest {

```
@isTest static void testJsonToCranes() {
    
    
    //Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockJsonBodyGenerator());
    
    //HTTPRequest req =new HTTPRequest();
   // HTTPResponse res= new MockJsonBodyGenerator().respond(req);
   
    HTTPResponse res= new HttpResponse();
    
    res.setBody('"id": {'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"stringValue": "IdValue1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"craneType": {'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "craneTypeValue1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"craneCategory":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "craneCategoryValue1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"craneControls":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "craneControlsValue1"'+
                '"loadCapacityType_0":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "loadCapacityType_0Value1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"trackWidthCraneType_0":{'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "trackWidthCraneType_0Value1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"engineControl_0": {'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "engineControl_0Value1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"sellerCompany": {'+'"value": {'+'"stringValue": "sellerCompanyValue1"'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"dismantlingnumber": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 10'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"usablePendulumStrutRadius": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 11'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"usableSolidStrutRadius": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 12'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"loadCapacityWeight_0": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 13'+
                '"FakeType": {'+'"Fake": {'+'"FakeValue": "FakeValue1"'+
                '"trackWidthCrane_0": {'+'"value": {'+'"doubleValue": 14');
        
       
    // Call method to test.
    // This causes a fake response to be sent
    // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
    // 
    List<Crane__c> cranes = JsonToCranesParser.JsonToCranes(res);
    
    
    // Verify response received contains fake values
    for(Crane__c var1 : cranes){
      
        System.assertEquals(var1.firestore_id__c, 'IdValue1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.Crane_Category__c, 'craneCategoryValue1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.Crane_Type__c, 'craneTypeValue1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.CraneControls__c, 'craneControlsValue1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.Engine_Control__c, 'engineControl_0Value1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.LoadCapacityType__c, 'loadCapacityType_0Value1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.Track_Width_Crane_Type__c, 'trackWidthCraneType_0Value1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.Seller_Company__c, 'sellerCompanyValue1');
        System.assertEquals(var1.Demontage_Number__c, 10);
        System.assertEquals(var1.Load_Capacity_Weight__c, 13);
        System.assertEquals(var1.Track_Width_Crane__c, 14);
        System.assertEquals(var1.Usable_Pendulum_Radius__c, 11);
        System.assertEquals(var1.Usable_Solid_Radius__c , 12);
   
        
      }  
   
    
    
    
    
    

}
```

}

Any advice please?

Comment: If you are seeing any blue-covered lines in your class, it is covering it.  Most likely there is something causing your code to return.  Review the last blue line and see if you can determine what might be forcing your code to stop.

Comment: Also, convert your firestore_id to an external ID field unique.  If you do that, you can just do an  "upsert myCranes firestore_Id__c" and remove the query and loop that attempts to find an existing record.